# Pepper Flash echo cancellation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using pepper flash (PPAPI) we cannot get audio echo cancellation to work. The below settings are what we use, which do work in Adobe's flash plugin NPAPI.

Changing some of the settings can make the echo worse, for example changing echoPath to 128 is worse - but nothing seems to solve our problem.

```
            publishMic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone(micList.selectedIndex);
            publishMic.rate = DEFAULT_MIC_RATE;
            var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
            options.nonLinearProcessing = true;
            options.echoPath = 256;
            options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;

            publishMic.framesPerPacket = 10;

            publishMic.enhancedOptions = options;
            publishMic.codec = SoundCodec.PCMA;
            publishMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
            publishMic.setLoopBack(false);
            publishMic.encodeQuality = 8;

            publishMic.setSilenceLevel(0,2000);
```

What is the correct process to eliminate echo?

Comment: Also make sure you are doing enough to minimize the echo.. Like not having the microphone pick up both voice AND voice-from-speakers (output). That would mean mute their vol so they not picked up mic or better still, use headphones to hear. Also latency settings for sound device might help (if available).

Comment: Is the response your answer? Then mark the response as answer please

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem in the PepperFlash in Chrome, take a look here : Issues [152314](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152314) and [144554](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=144554).